# VBA Getting results in another url but same window

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I'm working with VBA to fill a form in a URL and submiting to get results.
When I submit the form with correct values and submit via VBA, I get results in another URL but on the same window.

The problem is that I don't know how to change html reference to start scrapping data with this new url.

Here is my code:

```
    'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    'to refer to the HTML document returned
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "http://url..."
    'Wait until IE is done loading page
    Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Connecting with http://url..."
        DoEvents
    Loop
    'show text of HTML document returned
    Set html = IE.document
    'close down IE and reset status bar
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""

    Set txtArea = html.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0)
    txtArea.Value = txtArea_data

    Set formSubmit = html.getElementsByName("submit")(1)
    formSubmit.Click

    '-------------Get results
'Dim html_results As HTMLDocument
IE.navigate "http://new_url" 'Im not sure if I must do it this way...
'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Connecting with http://new_url..."
    DoEvents
Loop
Set html = IE.document
Dim trResults As IHTMLElementCollection
Set trResults = html.getElementsByClassName("tr")
MsgBox (trResults.Length) 'At this point, trResults always have 0 results...
```

Have you any idea to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: At a minimum, when you `Set IE = Nothing` you cannot continue to use the InternetExplorer object in subsequent commands. Additionally, submitting the form should carry you to another web page but you do not wait for it to load before attempting to `.Navigate` to a new URL altogether. I strongly suspect that the form submission is incorrect but that is speculation without seeing the source of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new approach, and still don't work.
I've used `IE.Visible = True`, so I could check that I get many `<tr>` results on the results page.

```
Dim rowNumber As Long
Dim txtArea_data As String
Dim txtArea As Object
Dim formSubmit As Object

Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "http://url..."

Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Connecting with http://url..."
    DoEvents
Loop

Set html = IE.document

rowNumber = 4
For rowNumber = 4 To 120 'Rows.Count

    txtArea_data = txtArea_data & Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value & Chr(10)

Next rowNumber

Set txtArea = html.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0)
txtArea.Value = txtArea_data

Set formSubmit = html.getElementsByName("submit")(1)
formSubmit.Click

'Wait until results
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

'-------------Get results
'At this point, the page URL with results has changed, but on the same tab. In the other code, I've used IE.navigate "http://new_url..." But a "Invalid file" message appears.
'-------------
'I suppose html var could be recharged with these new results data, but nothing happen...

Set html = IE.document
Dim trResults As IHTMLElementCollection
Set trResults = html.getElementsByClassName("tr")

MsgBox (trResults.Length) 'At this point, MsgBox returns O...

Set html = Nothing
```

Results page looks like:

```
<body>
  <table id="tabla-a">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>...</th>
        <th>...</th>
        <th>...</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Is there anything I could tell you to make to help you finding the problem?
Thanks!

***EDIT***

Oh my God! I've been using `Set trResults = html.getElementsByClassName("tr")` instead of Set `trResults = html.getElementsByTagName("tr")` !!!

Thanks for your time!

What should I do now? Edit the original question with the final solution or close the entire question?
I don't use Stackoverflow too much to ask questions...

Thanks!